# How do I update a user's manager in v1.0 of the new Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I can *get* the manager using the '/v1.0/users/${id}/manager' endpoint. But how do I update the users manager? Many permutations result in errors. The following one does not:

```
PATCH /v1.0/users/${id}
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ey...

manager: {
    id: ${managerId}
}
```

Yet when I list the direct reports, the update is not reflected. I have been attempting various permutations and any help is greatly appreciated. Please note, not having the update request result in an error does not equal success. The updated information must be retrieved correctly as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies.  It looks like we have a broken link for this topic in the docs (Assign Manager incorrectly points to list manager).  Please use this topic on GitHub https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_manager.md.  Also the documented permission scope that you need is incorrect and will need fixing.  The scopes that will work are Directory.ReadWrite.All or Directory.AccessAsUser.All.  The user will also need to be a privileged user (like a tenant admin or a user management admin).

The request will look something like this:

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id>/manager/$ref
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: xxx

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id>"
}
```

I'll file a bug to get the link fixed and the incorrect scopes.  Please let us know if this works for you.

UPDATE:  The link has been fixed and the topic is available here:  https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_manager

Hope this helps,