# Assign a manager to a user using Microsoft Python SDK for Azure

Tags: python, azure, api, assign

Ok MS Graph/Python Gurus.  How do I populate (assign a manager) to a user via the Azure Python SDK? If there is a way can you point me to it. I went as far as looking through the Python SDK source and I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I populate (assign a manager) to a user via the Azure Python SDK?

AFAIK, as of now, assigning a manager via Python SDK is not possible.

Alternatively, you can use REST API, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example):

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/10f17b99-784c-4526-8747-aec8a3159d6a/manager/$ref
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6ea91a8d-e32e-41a1-b7bd-d2d185eed0e0"
}
```

References: [graph api assign manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928883/graph-api-assign-manager), [How do I update a user's manager in v1.0 of the new Microsoft Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824280/how-do-i-update-a-users-manager-in-v1-0-of-the-new-microsoft-graph-api), and [Assign a manager using Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937093/assign-a-manager-using-microsoft-graph-net-client-library)